# Using a double groupBy in lodash

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

So I am trying to categorize an array of objects by a certain attribute. Using groupBy works great the first time. Now I need to loop through those groupings and group them again based on a separate attribute. I am having trouble with this can someone help me out?

TS

```
this.accountService.getAccountListWithBalance().subscribe(accounts => {
      this.accountList = _.groupBy(accounts, 'category');
      for (var property in this.accountList) {
        if (this.accountList.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          this.accountList.property = _.groupBy(this.accountList.property, 'subcategory');
        }
      }

generateArray(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return {key:key, value:obj[key]}});
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of generateArray(accountList)">
  <strong>{{ item.key }}</strong>
  <li *ngFor="let i of item.value">{{i.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The HTML isnt set for the next level of interation but I know it isnt working if I just console log the resulting object. Like I said its being sorted the first time just not the second time.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share the json response returned by account service api

Comment: what is the data structure of your accounts model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by just changing my syntax. Using `[]` instead of `.` so the working code is as follows.

```
this.accountService.getAccountListWithBalance().subscribe(accounts => {
      this.accountList = _.groupBy(accounts, 'category');
      for (var property in this.accountList) {
        if (this.accountList.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          this.accountList[property] = _.groupBy(this.accountList[property], 'subcategory');
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you are looping through accounts grouped by category, you should try group each category grouped item based on `subcategory` like this;

```
this.accountList = _.groupBy(accounts, 'category');
    _.foreach(this.accountList, function(categoryAccount) { 
              _.groupBy(categoryAccount, 'subcategory');
            });
```